# Using a C++ fundamental type as a class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class for D-dimensional 'geometrical' vectors:

```
template <size_t D>
class Vector;
```

I would like to use the `float` fundamental type as the 1-dimensional specialization of this template class.

Is it possible to define such a specialization?
The naïve approach

```
template<> using Vector<1> = float;
```

does not compile

Comment: `Vector<Dim, Type>` seems more appropriated...

Comment: It is a simplified declaration of the template just to exemplify the question.

Comment: I think yes. You just need to add a special implementation the one dimension case.

Comment: It is pretty trivial to write a class specialization containing one member of type 'float'. But my question is more general: "is it possible to use a type as a specialization of a template class?"

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a type as a specialization, I do so quite frequently in this code: https://github.com/SubstituteR/MoarPtr/blob/main/function_pointer.h

Comment: Do you mean you want `std::is_same_v<Vector<1>, float> == true` or do you want some member inside `Vector<1>` to have the type `float`? If the former, I would hate to be the user of this "vector" class that isn't a container at all.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an existing type in place of a specialization, but you can use a typedef to do the switching:

```
template <std::size_t D>
class Vector_impl { };

template <std::size_t D>
using Vector = std::conditional_t<
    D == 1,
    float,
    Vector_impl<D>
>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Vector<1>, float>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Vector<2>, Vector_impl<2>>);
```

You could also use an intermediate type trait to perform more advanced selection logic (*à la* `template <std::size_t D> using Vector = typename Vector_selector<D>::type`).

Comment: Thank you for this solution. An intermediate type trait is exactly what I am currently using for this problem. Your solution is basically a 'rephrased' type trait too. It would be really interesting to find something without additional types.

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov I'm afraid that's not possible. The closest would be to have the specialization inherit from the target type, but that's not an option for fundamental types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cpp
template<>
class Vector<1>
```

To achieve the behavior you are looking for.

See: https://godbolt.org/z/T7ME65Wv1 for a trivial example.

If you are wanting to conditionally choose the underlying storage type, you can do this

```cpp
template <size_t D>
class Vector
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<D == 1, float, T>; //T is your choice.
public:
    type data[D];
};
```

See:
https://godbolt.org/z/fMKMrh7Ex

Comment: This is an obvious solution. But I'm looking for something elegant, something in this style: `using Vector<1> = decimal;`

Comment: I've adjusted the example where such behavior is possible.

Comment: This solution requires accessing to the scalar value as `v.data`. It is possible to write an explicit `(float)` operator for the template specialization, but anyway it looks a little bit clumsy.

Comment: Arguably one would consider the behavior of Vector<1> being incongruent with Vector<D> ; D > 1 to be clumsy. Is there a reason you want Vector<1> to act differently than Vector<D> ; D > 1?

Comment: In brief, in contexts where I use Vector<1> a simple float work just well. And I must admit that it breaks the consistency of the interface.